# ARIMA Time Series Graph in R

Tags: r, arima

When I create a graph (ie `plot()`) with my date data on the x-axis and polling data on the y-axis all works well.

But when I covert the polling data with `arima` and try to add the converted data with my dates (*which worked beforehand*) the message,

> “Error: unexpected symbol in "plot(x,y)"

Appears where it did not beforehand.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Politicalpollingdata <- arima(politicalparty, order=c(0,1,1))                    

Futurepoliticalforecast <- forecast(Politicalpollingdata, h=20)

plot(Datedata, Futurepoliticalforecast, main = "Political Party’s Polling Data", 
ylab = "% of Votes", xlab = "Years / Months")
```

Does anyone know

A) why this occurs after I convert the polling data with the
`arima` command?

B) is there a way to be able to use time series data in the `x-axis` (preferably” y/m/d”)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

- Data was not converted using ARIMA, you made a model. When you ask it for a forecast, it will output an object of type forecast (a list) which includes a lot more information than just the fitted values. You will be able to access the fitted values using  `Futurepoliticalforecast$fitted`.
- Yes, there are many. You have not produced your data so I don't know what the problem is. However, x-labels act very well when the input is in type Date, but again, I don't know what the problem could be for your data.